# Sort time discrepancy

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, analysis

I've written a program for a school assignment that prints out the time it takes to sort an array of integers using six different sorting algorithms: selection sort, bubble sort, merge sort, quick sort, heap sort, and radix sort. The integer arrays range from 50,000 to 300,000 elements.

What's bothering me is with the first result of the merge sort, heap sort, radix sort, and the `Collections.sort()` method.

The first array, the 50,000 element array, takes longer to sort than the subsequent, longer arrays. Each subsequent, larger array takes an increasing amount of time to sort, as I'd expect. I'm wondering what's causing this, whether it's overhead that I'm not accounting for or whether there's a problem with my algorithms or program.

I've attached a link to a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLCWK.png) showing the results

Below is an example of the code

```
    int[] array = generateIntegers(50000);
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    radixSort(array);
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(end - start);

    int[] arrayTwo = generateIntegers(100000);
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    radixSort(arrayTwo);
    end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(end - start);

    int[] arrayThree = generateIntegers(150000);
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    radixSort(arrayThree);
    end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(end - start);
```

Console:

```
    40
    10
    13
```

And the `generateIntegers(n)` method

```
public static int[] generateIntegers(int size)
{
    int[] arr = new int[size];

    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        arr[i] = rand.nextInt(integerRange);
    return arr;
}
```

Thanks for any input!

Comment: It's very likely this is a result of the JIT doing its thing. Though without knowing what `generateIntegers` actually does, hard to tell. Remember, the absolute time of a sort is highly dependent on the input array's data. Unless you ran this test many, many times with the same results, it could just happen to be that `generateIntegers` produced a 'bad' array the first time.

Comment: I don't think it's a 'bad' array, I've run it multiple times and had the same outcomes. It may be a problem with the `generateIntegers` method, though. I've added it to the original post.

Comment: What happens if you run *the entire series* multiple times in a row, in the same JVM run?

Comment: (Also note that you can just generate a single `static Random` and use it continuously, unless you're calling `generateIntegers` from multiple threads.)

Comment: Have you done a 'warmup' of your VM? Execute the entire code you want to measure several times in a loop before doing any measurements.

Comment: chrylis, isnot2bad, running it multiple times in the same JVM did the trick and the elapsed time increased as I was expecting. Thanks! Would this be chalked up to the JIT compiler, as aruisdante mentioned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very complex and hard to correctly measure performance of a java program, especially when you want to compare different algorithms due to the fact that the JVM does many clever optimizations during execution (e.g. see [Wikipedia: Java performance - Adaptive optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_performance#Adaptive_optimization)).

One major rule is to perform a "JVM warm-up" before measuring anything. This gives the JVM time to "learn" about your code and how it is used (execution profile) to optimize it. Then you should calculate a mean execution time value over several executions.

Your performance measurement method might look like that:

```
public long measure(Runnable testCode, int warmupIterations, int testIterations) {
    // warmup
    for(int i = 0; i < warmupIterations; i++) {
        testCode.run();
    }

    // test
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i = 0; i < testIterations; i++) {
        testCode.run();
    }
    long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;

    return elapsed / testIterations;
}
```

Comment: That's great, I'll have to read up on that. When I did a "JVM warm-up" as suggested the subsequent results were more in line with what I was expecting. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. You should play around with different warmup iterations. If you add time measurement to the warmup iterations, you'll see how execution time drops with every iteration until it reaches a (somehow) stable value.